# NextJS component having wrong class applied when SSR on production but shows correctly when in dev

Tags: reactjs, express, sass, next.js, server-side-rendering

Just like the title says, when in production and server-side rendered, nextjs (or react?) is applying the incorrect class to random components.

Basically, I've got a loop where I case switch on a string for a particular component:

```
switch (myData.action) {
        case 'event':
            theLog = <><LTEvent eventName={hlper().eventToName(myData.sunkShip)} eventAction={hlper().eventToAction(myData.sunkShip)}></LTEvent></>
            break;
        case 'manual_log':
            theLog = <><LTManual>{hlper().parseLog(myData.sunkShip)} {myData.action}</LTManual></>
            break;
etc...}
```

each LT-component is its own component with its own styling. Like this for instance:

```
export default function LTManual({ children }) {   

    return (
        
        <div className={`${styles.manual_log} vinceTestClass`}>
            {children}
        </div>

    )
}
```

Everything works fine when I'm working locally on dev. but as soon as it's built and running on production server side rendering, it randomly assigns the wrong className to (seemingly) random components.

For instance, sometimes, on the `LTEvent` component, the class applied would be the one from the `LTManual` component (even with the `VinceTestClass` fake class there that I added to just see what was going on.) The dom structure and data are all correct, so it's loading the proper component but for some reason mixing up the classNames.

So, I'll get something like this:

```
<div class="logEntry_manual_log__148BX vinceTestClass">...
```

when it should be

```
<div class="logEntry_flagged__2aH2E">...
```

as I said before, everything else in the component is fine and it works when running the dev server. I'm at a loss now.

While I don't think it's my problem, I added styled-components to the _document and added a .babelrc file and set `"plugins": [["styled-components", { "ssr": true }]]`

I can also use the same code and render the page client-side totally fine if I ajax the same data into the page post-render.

Every other page I've got renders and works fine (as far as I can tell) the only other culprits I can think of are that I'm using SASS and also a custom express server but this page is fairly basic and nothing crazy going on there so it *should* work.

Comment: Could you provide a [mre]?

Comment: I might have to start a new project with just the pieces that are broken. let me see if I can do that, @juliomalves

Comment: Hi @Chenzo any update on this? Did you get a solution?